# how to open a function in new window ?or new tab?

Tags: html

I am calling a function in my controller from a button click ....
I  want the function to be opened in a new window how can we get that

ex:
now my url is

"http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/index.php/adminController/adminDegree"

with a button click i am calling a function degreechk in my adminController

I want the url

"http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/index.php/adminController/degreechk "

to be opened in a new window
How can i get  the new url in a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle it on the View page only if you are submitting the form. add attribute **target="_blank"** in your form tag. For Ex:-

```
<form id="search" action="/search" method="get" target="_blank">
  <input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="search">
  <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Answer" tabindex="110">

</form>
```